# Can't get BeautifulSoup to recognize columns correctly (Python, xml (Excel web) html file)

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm working with a number of files of this format (eliminated styling html):

```html
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

<head>
  <meta name="Generator" content="SAS Software Version 9.3, see www.sas.com">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <colgroup>
      <col>
        <col>
          <col>
            <col>
    </colgroup>
    <colgroup>
      <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2" colspan="4" scope="colgroup">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="header" colspan="2" scope="colgroup">SubDistrict</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header" scope="col">Title1
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td class="header" scope="col">Title2
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rowheader" rowspan="12" scope="rowgroup">M1</td>
        <td class="rowheader" scope="row">1.1</td>
        <td class="rowheader" scope="row">var1</td>
        <td class="rowheader" scope="row">TOTAL</td>
        <td class="data">7</td>
        <td class="data">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        etc...
```

In the browser, they appear like this:

[image]

And I've written the following in Beautiful Soup, which I'm brand new to:

```html
def read_xls(file):
    f = open(file)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
    
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    #table[0].thead.find_all('tr')[1].td.get_text()
    
    data = []
    for tr in table[0].find_all('tr'):
        temp = []
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            temp.append(td.get_text())
        data.append(temp)
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But my code is resulting in significant column alignment problems:

[image]

Any advice on how to improve my BeautifulSoup code to parse this more correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a public page you are parsing, could you share a link to it so that we can have a full table to experiment with? Thanks!

Comment: It is a public page, but the files are only downloadable in bulk (it's an Indian government website). Here's the url to a zip of them though: https://nrhm-mis.nic.in/HMISReports/frmDownload.aspx?download=wqJDHZVkFe7jkTbCvX6Y8yY/TJhbpm1W2WyEC0VNP45GkBd3SMIF9lTO72QMVWpbsOV3CTZI2vax5pHgYnOuy9YaO9awMH375sHMUU9gsaYSKaohEyfuL8V4bOKsipiCqtF3FX53YVkGFwVd75UVv1PkPUmN66XUM2GSt1L2S6k=

Comment: @alecxe here's just 1 file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pr5xw0reryf943k/J%20-%20Sundargarh_January.html?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

If I understood well this is what you wanted to extract:

[image]

You should be able to get it with the following code:

```
def read_xls(file):
    f = open(file)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
    tbody = soup.find('tbody')
    data = []
    trs = tbody.findAll('tr')
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in tds:
            data.append(td.text)

    return pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

Comment: I'm wanting to extract the entire table, with the same organization in which it renders in html, but as a dataframe. Does that clarify?

Comment: have you tried df = pd.read_html() ? as an argument use your html code from the file.

Comment: Yes, it renders similar to this. It's a bit worse though, as it also misses the column headers.